# How to wait for child components being bound in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a component (SomeComponent) which creates other child components (ChildComponent). I wonder how i can wait for the child components getting bound to a reference array. I would like to call methods in SomeComponent and its ChildComponents but get an empty array (childs). I tried waiting via onMount and await tick() in the parent before calling calledFromParent() but nothing works. How do i wait for the childs array being filled? (Note: my code is working if i delay the calls via setInterval in the parent)

```html
<!-- SomeComponent -->

<script>

    import ChildComponent

    let data = {childs: []}
    let childs = []

    export function calledFromParent(pData) {
  
        data = pData
        
        // maybe wait for tick() here?
    
        console.log(childs.length) // 0
        
        // then call function in childs[i]
    }

</script>


{#each data.childs as child, index}
    <ChildComponent bind:this={childs[index]}/>
{/each}
```

**Edit:** data gets loaded async in parent and then injected via calledFromParent(pData) into SomeComponent

Comment: [Your code seems to be working nicely](https://svelte.dev/repl/f7e71ffd468645c78a235189e01cb2a8?version=3.55.0). It might be that your `data.childs` is loaded asynchronous which is why it works with the `setTimeout`?

Comment: Thanks @Tholle I think you are onto something. I'll try to change the code to show how 'data' is injected into SomeComponent.

Comment: I think await tick() does the trick. Thanks again @Tholle